# Is it possible to have external IOT device publish to IBM cloud node-red aedes mqtt broker?

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, node-red

I am new to MQTT. Is it possible to have an external IOT device that can publish it's readings in MQTT format and use the aedes MQTT broker node and a subscriber node in node-red that is installed in the IBM cloud environment to receive the payloads?

Currently I have a simple setup within node-red with the publish and subscribe nodes when using the 'localhost:1883' as a server address. Do I need to have a server with IP address to make this work?

Where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.

You can only access Node-RED running on IBM Cloud via HTTP/HTTPS, you will not be able to connect to the any broker you ran in the Node-RED process externally.

This is because the Node-RED instance is behind a reverse HTTP/HTTPS proxy.

You could deploy Node-RED in a Docker container or on a Virtual machine, or just make use of an external MQTT broker. But without a much better understanding of the whole problem you are trying to solve it is impossible to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Currently I have with Node-red with a HTTP endpoint in it that receives payloads from an external device. I got the question if alternatively the device could send its messages over MQTT instead of HTTP. I guess I need an external MQTT broker than.